# How to display a dialog with (multiselect listview) before displaying "app would like to send you push notifications" dialog box

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, uialertview

I would like to display a pop-up where I'll ask the user about their preferences related to the push notifications and for that one, I want to display a list of options to the user. User can select more than one options.

I think that I'll have to display a tableview inside the UIAlertView, but it is deprecated now. So, how can I display a pop (with some small message + multiple select list ) before the APN system permissions dialog in **Swift**.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message:message, preferredStyle: .Alert)
            let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { _ in
                acceptNotification = true //code to execute when the user taps that OK
            }
            alert.addAction(action)
           //you can add more actions
            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true){ // this part if provided, will be invoked after the dismissed controller's viewDidDisappear: callback is invoked. 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm going to handle this another way. I'll create a settings page, where user can select the preference.

Comment: Cool. I just answered what you asked about ;)